# OpenCart Custom Fields in Order History

Tags: php, sql, opencart2.x

Custom Fields in Order History OC 2.0.3.1

Trying to insert two custom fields into the order history. I have done the following code edits and manually entered two columns into the database(tracking_number and check_number) and it is not working. I am not getting any errors, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

In my order_history.tpl file I added:

```
<td class="text-left"><?php echo $history['tracking_number']; ?></td>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo $history['check_number']; ?></td>
```

And

```
<td class="text-left"><?php echo $column_tracking_number; ?></td>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo $column_check_number; ?></td>
```

In my order_info.tpl file I added:

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-tracking-number"><?php echo $entry_tracking_number; ?></label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="tracking_number" id="input-tracking-number" size="50" />
              </div>
            </div>
```

In my controller order.php file I added the proper language files and this into the history array:

```
'tracking_number'     => $result['tracking_number'], 
'check_number'     => $result['check_number'],
```

In my model order.php file I changed the following:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT oh.date_added, os.name AS status, oh.comment, oh.tracking_number,  oh.check_number, oh.notify FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_history oh LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os ON oh.order_status_id = os.order_status_id WHERE oh.order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "' AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY oh.date_added ASC LIMIT " . (int)$start . "," . (int)$limit);
```

in my checkout/order.php

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "order_history SET order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', order_status_id = '" . (int)$order_status_id . "', notify = '" . (int)$notify . "', comment = '" . $this->db->escape($comment) . "', tracking_number = '" . (int)$tracking_number . "', date_added = NOW()");
```

And

```
public function addOrderHistory($order_id, $order_status_id, $comment = '', $tracking_number = '', $notify = false) {
  $this->event->trigger('pre.order.history.add', $order_id);
```

Now a "0" appears in the tracking_number field no matter what.

Comment: What is the datatype of field `tracking_number` ?

Comment: that's unique number from shipping company..example : BHC21315457896154

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `(int)` from your insert query. If your tracking number is in alphanumeric form. Your insert query should look like :

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "order_history SET order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', order_status_id = '" . (int)$order_status_id . "', notify = '" . (int)$notify . "', comment = '" . $this->db->escape($comment) . "', tracking_number = '" . $this->db->escape($tracking_number) . "', date_added = NOW()");
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your availability to help my problem, I've tried to remove (int) before but the result value (SQL fields) is always "0"

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add it to the History function in the catalog/controller/api/order.php file.

Look for the codes:

```
$keys = array(
            'order_status_id',
            'notify',
            'append',
            'comment'
        );
```

and

```
if ($order_info) {
            $this->model_checkout_order->addOrderHistory($order_id, $this->request->post['order_status_id'], $this->request->post['comment'], $this->request->post['notify']);
```

You may also need to add it to the bottom of the order_info.tpl file in the AJAX json script:

```
$('#button-history').on('click', function() {
if(typeof verifyStatusChange == 'function'){
if(verifyStatusChange() == false){
  return false;
}else{
  addOrderInfo();
}
}else{
addOrderInfo();
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=sale/order/api&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&api=api/order/history&order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'order_status_id=' + encodeURIComponent($('select[name=\'order_status_id\']').val()) + '&notify=' + ($('input[name=\'notify\']').prop('checked') ? 1 : 0) + '&append=' + ($('input[name=\'append\']').prop('checked') ? 1 : 0) + '&comment=' + encodeURIComponent($('textarea[name=\'comment\']').val()),
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#button-history').button('loading');         
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#button-history').button('reset');   
    },
    success: function(json) {
        $('.alert').remove();

        if (json['error']) {
            $('#history').before('<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + json['error'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
        } 

        if (json['success']) {
            $('#history').load('index.php?route=sale/order/history&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>');

            $('#history').before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

            $('textarea[name=\'comment\']').val('');

            $('#order-status').html($('select[name=\'order_status_id\'] option:selected').text());          
        }           
    },          
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
});
```